# How can I see what updates are available for a pinned HomeBrew formula?

Tags: homebrew

I have pinned a HomeBrew formula, using `brew pin python`. How do I see which updates are available for this formula if it were unpinned?

Answer (score 0):

Easy: just run `brew outdated`:

```
$ brew outdated
python (3.7.3) < 3.7.4 [pinned at 3.7.3]
...
```